# My python installation is broken/corrupted. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, redhat, yum

I followed these instructions on my RedHat Linux version 7 server (which originally just had Python 2.6.x installed):

beginning of instructions

install build tools

```
sudo yum install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel git-core -y
```

install python 2.7 and change default python symlink

```
sudo yum install python27-devel -y
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

yum still needs 2.6, so write it in and backup script

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/yum /usr/bin/_yum_before_27
sudo sed -i s/python/python2.6/g /usr/bin/yum
sudo sed -i s/python2.6/python2.6/g /usr/bin/yum
```

should display now 2.7.5 or later:

```
python -V
```

end of instructions

The above commands and comments were taken from:

http://www.lecloud.net/post/61401763496/install-update-to-python-2-7-and-latest-pip-on

The python -v command returned this:

```
-bash: python: command not found
```

Now it is as if I have no Python installed.  I don't want yum to break.  I tried installing Python 3.4.

`whereis python` shows this:

python: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python2.6-config /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python3.4m-config /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/bin/python3.4 /usr/local/bin/python3.4m /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

What should I do now?  I want a working installation of Python.  For certain things I'm doing, I need it to be 2.7 or higher.  I want yum to still work.

Comment: Why didn't you just install the `python27` package and leave it at that?

Comment: It didn't seem to be working.  I followed some instructions I found online for doing it.  But my results from python -V showed 2.6.x was still installed.

Answer (score 4):

Do

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: I don't know how but this worked for me ! I "accidentally" removed some .so files and this fixed it.

Comment: Thats removing all broken links to python, then adding a new soft link that "translates" the install name python2.7 where it was installed, to the pretty name python  you are used to running in your excecution path

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue while upgrading ubuntu 18 to 19, this made it:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
do-release-upgrade
```

From:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1825655

Answer (score 1):

For me, nothing worked except this one:

```
unlink /usr/bin/python3
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3
```

Credit: https://josephgeis.dev/2020/04/upgrading-to-ubuntu-20-04-python3/

Answer (score 0):

This is easily fixed by installing the `python27` package via `yum`. It should install in `/usr/bin`, and may overwrite the `/usr/bin/python` symlink that should be pointing to 2.6. If it did (just run `ls -l python*` in `/usr/bin` to see), remove the symlink and point it back to 2.6. Next create a symlink for `/usr/local/bin/python` pointing at `/usr/bin/python2.7`. Finally, modify your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (whichever you use) to have `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your PATH:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

at the very end of the file. This way, `/usr/bin/python` remains linked to Python 2.6, which is what the system expects, and when you run `python` at the command line it'll start up 2.7. You shouldn't have to make any changes to the `yum` script either - just blanket replacing `python` with `python2.6` without understanding what you're doing is not a very good idea.

I'd also recommend installing Python 3.4 in `/usr/local/bin` if possible, where the binary will be named `python3` by convention. Even if it installs in `/usr/bin`, you'll still have the choice of running `python3` or `python3.4` to specify which version you want. I work on a CentOS system that has each version of Python from 2.4 up to 3.4 installed, all in `/usr/local/bin` (I'm sure this was done manually, and not via `yum`), while the only `python*` in `/usr/bin` is 2.6. I couldn't find a `python3` package for RedHat (I may not have been looking hard enough), so I'd recommend building the latest version from [source](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tgz) (3.4.3 as of this writing). Unzip the tarball in a suitable directory, check out the README file, then, in the `Python-3.4.3` directory, run `./configure --help` to see what the options are, and if you need to change anything. As long as you have `gcc` installed, and don't need to link to any weird math libraries or anything, you should just be able to run:

```
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

and it'll install to `/usr/local/bin`. Check the messages at the end of the `make` step, as it'll list any modules it wasn't able to build there. Fails usually happen because you don't have a required library installed, so look in `setup.py` in the base directory in the `detect_modules()` function (starting on line 449, and stretching all the way down to line 1564). Install both the lib and the `-devel` packages so you get the necessary headers.

This same process can also be followed if you want to install the latest 2.7.9, instead of RH's 2.7.5. One of the major (in my eyes) advantages of 2.7.9 is that `pip` is installed by default, making third-party module installation that much easier.

Good luck!