# -bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, centos

I am new in centos.I am try to do an application on it.For my application I need to install python 2.7.But the default one on server was python 2.6. So tried to upgrade the version .And accidentally I deleted the folder /usr/bin/python.After that I Installed python 2.7 through **make install**.I created the folder again /usr/bin/python and run command  **sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python**.  After this when I tried to run **YUM commands** I am getting the error

**-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied**

drwxrwxrwx 2 root root        4096 Mar  8 00:19 python

this is permission showing for the directory /usr/bin/python

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921697/my-python-installation-is-broken-corrupted-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` should be an executable or a binary, not a directory

Comment: I have changed it to a executable file now I am getting the error   -bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Answer (score 11):

CentOS requires that `/usr/bin/python` be pointed to Python 2.6, not any other version. Run the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/python
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

to at least fix that part of it. Next time you're building Python, use the defaults and install it to `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/bin`. That's what the `/usr/local` hierarchy is for - user-installed programs. `/usr` and `/usr/bin` should only be for system-installed programs (such as those installed by `yum` or its graphical equivalents), and you should keep out unless you know what you're doing. To use identically-named programs in `/usr/local/bin` instead of their counterparts in `/usr/bin`, open your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (whichever your system uses) and add the following as the last line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Restart your shell session, and you should be all set.

Comment: thank you for answer But I have one more issue ,the file path /usr/bin/python2.6 is also not there .I think I have deleted it earlier.So what  should I do? I think because of that after I followed your steps I am getting the error.   -bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: @aneesh In the future, **please** don't go around randomly deleting stuff you don't understand. Linux doesn't have any sort of command-line "Trash" by default that you can use to undelete, unless you made a backup of the system before you started messing around. You can *try* to build [2.6.9](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6.9/) from source, but no guarantees that it'll work. You may need to reinstall your system.

Comment: I have build it using 2.6.9. But when running command getting the error  bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          37 Mar  8 01:19 python -> /home/odoouser/Python-2.6.9      this is the permission showing

Comment: @aneesh did you run `make install` after building 2.6.9, and configure it beforehand to install into `/usr/bin`? What you just posted looks like a symlink to the directory where you unpacked the 2.6.9 source. Like I said before, `/usr/bin/python` has to be a link to a binary, or an actual binary itself, not a link to a directory. You can't "run" a directory...

Comment: @aneesh and that last part was your problem. Why did you do that? First off, you need to run `./configure --prefix=/usr` to get it to install to the right place. Delete your symlink, run `make clean`, then the `./configure` command above, then `sudo make install`. Don't touch, delete, move, or symlink **anything** in `/usr/bin` until you've determined that everything worked.

Comment: @aneesh Let me say it in plain English - **don't make a symlink to `/usr/bin/python`!**

Comment: I have done eveything as you said but still getting the error  -bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: now I try to run whereis python is  like this        python: /usr/bin/python2.6-config /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python2.6-config /usr/local/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz

Comment: The `python2.6` binary is now in `/usr/local/bin`. Symlink it to `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python2.6`, and be done with it.

Comment: Just checking up, is the opening statement still valid? "CentOS requires that /usr/bin/python be pointed to Python 2.6". At some point in the future will CentOs change to Python 2.7 or Python 3 (serious question)? What was the version when you answered this question?

Answer (score 4):

yum doesn't work with python2.7.
You should do the following
`vim /usr/bin/yum`
        change 
        `#!/usr/bin/python`
        to 
        `#!/usr/bin/python2.6` 
        If your python2.6 was deleted, then reinstall them and point the directory in /usr/bin/yum to your python2.6 directory.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple; because the **Python** package was removed, the `yum` command won't work.

Please use below link to install packages:

[Go to Link and download python package](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/python27/python27-1.1-26.1.el7.x86_64.rpm)

```sh
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/python27/python27-1.1-26.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python27-1.1-26.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Then `yum` will work.

Comment: If `/usr/bin/python` is a directory, this will probably fail.

Comment: There is not relation of python with yum. yum is a package manager available for centos/fedora/redhat. You can install the python package using `yum`. Also you can run command `whereis python` and update the output of that command as an interpreter.

Comment: You can check where yum utility runs from, it is in `/bin/yum`:  When you do `cat` its shows you in the first python interpreter   in `\bin\yum` PF first some line below :

`[root@osboxes ~]# cat /bin/yum
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
try:
    import yum
except ImportError:
    print >> sys.stderr, """\
`

Answer (score 0):

this problem is that yum file start head write #!/usr/local/bin/python2.6， write binary file， is not dir， is python binary file

Answer (score 0):

Resolution for CentOs 7:

```
dnf reinstall python-2.7.5-92.el7_9.x86_64
dnf reinstall yum
```

Remove python3 first using `dnf` if it is installed already.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied then

1. first remove python follow command line

   --  sudo rpm  -e python
2. second check which package install this command line

   -- sudo rpm -q  python
3. then install package

   -- sudo yum install python*

   i think this problem solve

Comment: error :sudo yum install python*
sudo: unable to execute /bin/yum: No such file or directory